# AFNetworking parsing json deeper

Tags: ios, json, afnetworking

I´m using AFNetworking to parse some json and absolutely love it.

Now i want to go a lever deeper. My json output looks something like this

```
-result
  -0
    rezept_id : value1
    rezept_name : value2
    rezept_zubereitung : value3
```

Everything works fine until here and I can parse the value. But now it goes on like this

```
-rezept_bilder
  -0    
    -bigfix

      file : value4
      file_path : value5
```

Now I want to parse the json attribute file value (value4) and display it in an image view. To display the image i would do something like this if it would be on the main.

```
[self.restuarantImageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[self.restuarantDetail objectForKey:@"file"]]];
```

but how do i tell him that the file value is not on the main but under

```
-rezept_bilder
 -0
  - bigfix
```

Here is the code I am using to parse the data to that point where I'm stuck.

```
-(void)makeRestuarantsRequests3{


    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.chefkoch.de/api/1.0/api-recipe.php?    zufall=1&divisor=0&limit=1"];

   NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                                                                    success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id responseObject) {
                                                                                        self.googlePlacesArrayFromAFNetworking3 = [responseObject objectForKey:@"result"];
                                                                                        NSDictionary *tempDictionary3= [self.googlePlacesArrayFromAFNetworking3 objectAtIndex:0];
                                                                                      self.zubereitung.text = [tempDictionary3 objectForKey:@"rezept_zubereitung"];
                                                                                             self.Name.text = [tempDictionary3 objectForKey:@"rezept_name"];


                                                                                    }
                                                                                    failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id responseObject) {
                                                                                        NSLog(@"Request Failed with Error: %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);


                                                                                    }];
```

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english, hope you guys understand where my problem is!

-----------EDIT

thanks got it working now :D

you realy healed me

this is how i did it

```
-(void)makeRestuarantsRequests3{


NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.chefkoch.de/api/1.0/api-recipe.php?zufall=1&divisor=0&limit=1"];

   NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                                                                    success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id responseObject) {
                                                                                        self.googlePlacesArrayFromAFNetworking3 = [responseObject objectForKey:@"result"];
                                                                                        NSDictionary *tempDictionary3= [self.googlePlacesArrayFromAFNetworking3 objectAtIndex:0];
                                                                                      self.zubereitung.text = [tempDictionary3 objectForKey:@"rezept_zubereitung"];
                                                                                             self.Name.text = [tempDictionary3 objectForKey:@"rezept_name"];


                                                                                        self.googlePlacesArrayFromAFNetworking5 =[tempDictionary3 objectForKey:@"rezept_bilder"];

                                                                                        NSDictionary *tempDictionary4= [self.googlePlacesArrayFromAFNetworking5 objectAtIndex:0];

                                                                                        NSDictionary *tempDictionary5 = [tempDictionary4 objectForKey:@"bigfix"];


                                                                                        [self.Bild setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[tempDictionary5 objectForKey:@"file"]]];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change it like below and see. If possible post the JSON of responseObject, to see more clearly.

```
self.googlePlacesArrayFromAFNetworking3 = [responseObject objectForKey:@"result"];                                                         

NSDictionary *tempDictionary3= [[self.googlePlacesArrayFromAFNetworking3 objectAtIndex:0] obejctForKey:@"bigfix"];

self.zubereitung.text = [tempDictionary3 objectForKey:@"rezept_zubereitung"];                                                                                             
self.Name.text = [tempDictionary3 objectForKey:@"rezept_name"];
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. havent testet it yet but i think you are missing the "rezept_bilder" object in your code ?

Comment: yes, change the "result" to "rezept_bilder" in the line 1. Hope you are getting an idea how to do it!